# Getting an average with a List

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to make this small windows forms application that lets you click a button, and it calculates how much you click per second. However I'm getting unwanted results.

The label is always either 0 or 1. My work here is using the Stopwatch class as a timer.

```
        public List<long> clickTimes = new List<long>();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    long last = 0;

    private void startCalc()
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

     private void stopCalc()
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }

    private void resetCalc()
    {
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    private long time()
    {
        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private bool isOn()
    {
        return stopwatch.IsRunning;
    }

    private long frequencyFromInterval(long ms)
    {
        return 1000 / ms;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isOn() == false)
        {
            startCalc();
        }
        last = time() - last;
        clickTimes.Add(last);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long avg = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < clickTimes.Count; i++)
        {
            avg = avg + clickTimes[i];
        }
        avg = avg / clickTimes.Count;
        avg = frequencyFromInterval(avg);
        label1.Text = "Avg. CpS: " + avg.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: From a simple design point of view you can quickly achieve this using Rx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your peroblem is in `divide` operation. It automaticly round the values to `long` because all the operands are of type `long` and result is `long`.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < clickTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += clickTimes[i];
    }
    double avg = sum / clickTimes.Count;
    double frequency = FrequencyFromInterval(avg);
    label1.Text = "Avg. CpS: " + frequency.ToString());
}

private double FrequencyFromInterval(double ms)
{
    return 1000 / ms;
}
```

Also there is a small error in `button1_Click` method. You use different values when find `last` and add to `clickTimes` list. You should cache the value you get by `time` method.

```
long time = time();
last = time  - last;
clickTimes.Add(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

From a rapid glimpse of your code I assume your issue is due to the fact you're using `long` type of values, which divided, can return only the integer part of a number. Try using `float` or `double` types.

Comment: the stopwatch uses long, how could I convert long to float?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, 
    long lNumber=...;
    float fNumber=(float)lNumber;
    float fNumber2=lNumber as float;

or it can be implicitly converted to float if you assign it to a float variable and one of the variables used in the division is a float.

Answer (score 0):

How about just use the [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535036%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function on your list, like this

```
double average = clickTimes.Average();
```